# Modality work list - Which items are returned for C-FIND request of a sequence?

Tags: dicom, fo-dicom

My question is a really basic question. Consider to query a modality work list to get some work items by a C-FIND query. Consider using a sequence (`SQ`) as *Return Key* attribute for the `C-FIND` query, for example: **[0040,0100]** (*Scheduled Procedure Step*) and universal matching.

What should I expect in the SCP's `C-FIND` response? Or, better say, what should I expect to find with regards of the scheduled procedure step for a specific work item? All the mandatory items that *Modality Work List Information Model* declare as encapsulated in the sequence? Should I instead explicitly issue a `C-FIND` request for those keys I want the SCP return in the response?

For example: if I want the SCP return the *Scheduled Procedure Step Start Time* **and** *Scheduled Procedure Start Date*, do I need to issue a specific `C-FIND` request with those keys or querying for *Scheduled Procedure Step* key is enough to force the SCP to send all items related to the *Scheduled Procedure Step* itself?

Comment: Have you tried specifying only the `(0040, 0100)` element as return key on a `C-FIND` to any freely available implementation of a DICOM server? [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/), for instance, or [DVTk](http://www.dvtk.org)'s SCP perhaps.

Comment: I already developed and tested my solution using DVTk RIS emulator and I deployed the solution on  two  production sites;  on both of them I query a real RIS and everything works. I get the Procedure Steps Sequence  by [0040,0100] key and the RIS responds with the set of items defined for the Scheduled Procedure Steps Sequence. The problem arise on 3rd production site where I don’t get  the items I expectd. Hospital IT ask me to explicitaly query the missing items: >Scheduled Procedure Step Start Time and >Pre-Medication.  I would like to know what DICOM standards say about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should include the Scheduled Procedure Step Start Time / Date Tags into the 0040,0100 sequence.

See also [Service Class Specifications](http://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/pdf/part04.pdf) (K6.1.2.2)

This will not ensure you will retrieve this information, because it depends on the Modality Worklist Provider, which information will be returned.
You could also request a Dicom Conformance Statement from the Modality Provider to know the necessary tags for request/retrieve.

Comment: I agree that the information returned depends on the Modality Worklist Provider, but I expect it at least can  provide the set of mandatary attributes.

Comment: In light of your first answer how do you interpret the sentence: C.2.2.2.6: "If the Key Attribute in the Identifier of a C-FIND request contains no Key Item Attribute (zero-length Item Tag), then all entities shall match this Attribute. This provides a universal matching like mechanism to request that the selected Key Attribute value (the entireSequence of Items) be returned in corresponding C-FIND responses."

Comment: Please see Table K.6-1, there you can see the Attributes for the Modality Worklist Information Model. The Matching Key Type will show you the required "R" and optional "O" fields in the 0040,0100 sequence.

Comment: Still im not understanding; Required Matching key attributes are attributes for which SCP should support a match, whereas Optional Matching Key attributes are attributes for which an SCU doesn’t expect  SCP to  support a match. How you can gather that from that table checking the Matching Key Type?

Comment: Well, of course you can keep your sequence blank, but this could lead to your problem description in your question. Some Vendors may accept this request others not. So, its better to always specify it, if you expect a result back. Thats why i wrote "you should include".
If the Worklist SCP expects this Tags or not should be specified in the Vendors Dicom Conformance Statement.

Comment: I agree with you, but the point now for me is "Are the equipments  that not accept the blank sequence request   still DICOM complaint?  I would expect if you declare your SCP  is DICOM complaint it respect the C.2.2.2.6 statement above.

Comment: It is a valid request, but due to restrictions of the provider (dicom conformance statement) it can be denied.

Answer (score 1):

As for table K.6-1, you can consider it as showing only the requirement of the SCP side or what SCP is required to use for matching key (i.e. query filter) and additional required attribute values to return (i.e. Return Key) with successful match.  It is up to SCP’s implementation to support matching against required key but you can always expect SCP to use the values in matching key for query filter.

Also note that, SCP is only required to return values for attributes that are present in the C-FIND Request. One exception is the sequence matching and there you have the universal matching like mechanism where you can pass a zero length ITEM to retrieve entire sequence.  So as stated in PS 3.4 section C.2.2.2.6, you can just include an empty ITEM (FFFE, E000) element with VR of SQ under Scheduled Procedure Step Sequence (0040, 0100) for universal matching.